# Informix - Syntax error on CREATE TABLE

Tags: informix, create-table

I keep having a cryptic "Syntax error" in this statement for an Informix database.

```
CREATE TABLE Historial
   (
    id_evento SERIAL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT  Historial_claves_primarias,
    foranea_CI_Persona INT REFERENCES Personas (CI) CONSTRAINT Historial_fk_Personas_CI,
    IP varchar(20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ip_vacia,
    query lvarchar(1000) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Historial_query_vacia,
    fecha_hora DATETIME NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fecha_historial_vacio
);
```

Can someone help me and point out what it is? I seriously cant see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found out that im supposed to give the precision of the measure as stated below, but with a cryptic error like that, what do you expect.

```
drop table if exists Historial;
CREATE TABLE Historial
(
    id_evento SERIAL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT  Historial_claves_primarias,
    foranea_CI_Persona INT REFERENCES Personas (CI) CONSTRAINT Historial_fk_Personas_CI,
    IP varchar(20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ip_vacia,
    query lvarchar(1000) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Historial_query_vacia,
    fecha_hora datetime year to minute not null constraint Historial_fecha_vacia
);
```

Comment: If, as I expect, you got `-201: A syntax error occurred`, then it is frustrating, but it is also quite hard to improve on what the grammar does when it sees `DATETIME` and does see `<units1> TO <units2>`.